# How to use @Query annotation for MongoDB for fetching documents between dates?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, rest, mongodb-query

I am trying to implement GET request with REST API with **Spring framework** and **MongoDB** on dates using **@Query** annotation.
My Query is to get all patients documents between specified admission dates.
I am getting this message.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Patients between dates not found.",
  "errorCode": 400
}
```

What is the Issue here? I am giving all my Controller, Service, Repository, and application.properties code below please help.

- **Controller:**

```
@GetMapping("/admissiondates")
public ResponseEntity<List<Patient>> getPatientsBtwnAdmissionDates(
            @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) String minDate,
            @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) String maxDate)
            throws PatientAdmissionException {
List<Patient>patientsBtwnDatesList = patientService.getPatientsBtwnAdmissionDates(minDate,maxDate);
return new ResponseEntity<>(patientsBtwnDatesList, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

- **Service:**

```
public List<Patient> getPatientsBtwnAdmissionDates(String minDate, String maxDate)
            throws PatientAdmissionException {
List<Patient> patientBtwnDatesList = patientRepository.getPatientsBtwnAdmissionDates(minDate, maxDate);
if (patientBtwnDatesList.isEmpty() == true) {
    throw new PatientAdmissionException("Service.PATIENTS_BTW_DATE_NOT_FOUND");
}
return patientBtwnDatesList;
}
```

- **Repository:**

```
@Query("{'admission_date': {$gte: ?0, $lte: ?1}}")
public List<Patient> getPatientsBtwnAdmissionDates(String minDate, String maxDate) throws PatientAdmissionException;
```

- **In application.properties:**

```
Service.PATIENTS_BTW_DATE_NOT_FOUND= Patients between dates not found.
```

- **Here is my sample patient Document:**

```
_id: 1015
patientName: "Hemant Srivastav"
gender: "male"
date_of_birth: 2006-07-18T18:30:00.000+00:00
admission_date: 2022-07-01T18:30:00.000+00:00
diagnosis: "broken arm"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following JPA method to get the list of patients based on the range of admission dates:

```
List<Patient> findByAdmissionDateBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);
```

Comment: For second method you shared this exception is coming: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property admissionDate found for type Patient! Did you mean 'admission_date'?

Comment: you should have a field in your Patient entity as admissionDate but I think you have defined it as admission_date either change the field name from admission_date to admissionDate in your entity or change the method signature to findByAdmission__dateBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate) here the method name should have two underscores between Admission and date.

Comment: Now it is parsing "Admission_date" only as "admission". I can't change admission_date in the document because that's how schema is defined in the whole collection. Please help with the @Query method.

Comment: what is the data type of your admission_date field?? 
If it is of type date then pass the parameters of type date instead of string to your existing repository method.

Comment: The field is of type date but I am using @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) in my controller which converts data sent to date type. I got this error before of types mismatch that is how I resolved it.